# Apple Wireless Keyboard does not reconnect reliably after reboot (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, apple

I tried to set up my Apple Wireless Keyboard with UbuntuGNOME 15.10, which for the most part works flawlessly until I reboot.

After rebooting, I have a 20% chance the keyboard reconnects and actually works, usually it connects and shows up in the BT device manager, but it does not recognize any input. In that case I am unable to disconnect it in order to pair it again. I need to unplug & replug the BT dongle in order to either get it to work again right away or to be able to re-pair it.

I was unable to find any problem description that fits my current issue, I hope someone can offer some suggestions as to how I would go about pinpointing the source of the issue.

Kind regards!

Some infos:

dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

```
[    0.197759] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    4.229878] pci 0000:ff:1e.3: [Firmware Bug]: reg 0x10: invalid BAR (can't size)
[   46.531698] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   46.531715] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   46.531719] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   46.531721] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   46.531730] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   46.710888] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   46.710890] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   46.710893] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   62.511313] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[   62.511318] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[   62.514069] input: Adriaan Bernsteins Tastatur as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:70/0005:05AC:0256.0006/input/input18
[   62.514286] apple 0005:05AC:0256.0006: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v0.50 Keyboard [Adriaan Bernsteins Tastatur] on 00:16:a4:0a:61:aa
[   91.462191] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   91.462202] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   91.462209] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  264.250991] input: Adriaan Bernsteins Tastatur as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:63/0005:05AC:0256.0007/input/input19
[  264.251500] apple 0005:05AC:0256.0007: input,hidraw3: BLUETOOTH HID v0.50 Keyboard [Adriaan Bernsteins Tastatur] on 00:16:a4:0a:61:aa
```

lsusb

```
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Apple Magic Mouse on Ubuntu 15.10 and a Macbook Retina Pro.

I could pair the mouse which worked until reboot. After reboot I could see the pairing, but couldn't reconnect. I use the Blueman applet which gave the error "Failed to connect Input/Output error".

A temporary fix was to delete the pairing, scan and connect the mouse which would work until reboot.

Whilst the mouse is connected, the command `lsmod | grep magic` returns:

```
$ lsmod | grep magic
hid_magicmouse        16384  0
hid                  118784  5 hidp,hid_generic,usbhid,hid_apple,hid_magicmouse
```

When the mouse wasn't connected, `hid_magicmouse` wasn't present.

Eventually I solved the problem by adding the line

> hid_magicmouse

to the file `/etc/modules`.

Now the mouse reconnects automatically on reboot.

Perhaps the same approach will work for you.